# Identify pixel data format in SDL

Tags: opengl, colors, textures, sdl

Running on OS X, I've loaded a texture in OpenGL using `SDL_Image` library (using `IMG_LOAD()` which returns `SDL_Surface*`). It appeared that the color channels have been swapped, i.e. I had to set `GL_BGRA` as a pixel format parameter in `glTexImage2D()`.

Is there a way to determine the correct data format (BGRA or RGBA or etc...) without just simply compiling and checking the texture? And what is the reason that SDL swaps these color channels?

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but I realized I am missing a big part of the solution. Basically, BGRA is preferred for unsigned 8 bit normalized textures on a lot of systems, where other types tend to use RGBA. However, I wasn't able to find a way to ask SDL_Image what format it output, which is rather key to making sure it matches what you tell OpenGL. These days, though, probably any image you load on any reasonable system is going to be BGRA ordered. RGBA or ARGB might pop up for HDR files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Following link has code examples of how to determine the channel shift for each component: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat#Code_Examples

From the site:

```
SDL_PixelFormat *fmt;
SDL_Surface *surface;
Uint32 temp, pixel;
Uint8 red, green, blue, alpha;
.
.
.
fmt = surface->format;
SDL_LockSurface(surface);
pixel = *((Uint32*)surface->pixels);
SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);

/* Get Red component */
temp = pixel & fmt->Rmask;  /* Isolate red component */
temp = temp >> fmt->Rshift; /* Shift it down to 8-bit */
temp = temp << fmt->Rloss;  /* Expand to a full 8-bit number */
red = (Uint8)temp;
```

You should be able to sort the Xmasks by value. Then you may determine if its RGBA or BGRA. If Xmask == 0 then the color channel does not exist.

I have no idea why the swaps occur.

Edit: Changed from Xshift to Xmask as the latter may be used to determine both location AND existance of color channels.

Comment: _"I have no idea why the swaps occur."_ Byte order very likely. No idea what version of OS X or even what processor architecture is involved here, but that is a more common problem on that platform than others.